# DataTemplate binding failing silently

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

I have a user control `MyUserControl` with two dependency properties `PropA` and `PropB`. In this user control, i have a tab control like this:

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=Views}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Controls:MyOtherControl Content="{Binding Content}"
                                         PropA="{Binding PropA, ElementName=MyUserControl}"
                                         PropB="{Binding PropB, ElementName=MyUserControl, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                </Controls:MyOtherControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The `PropA` binding works correctly. I can change the value in `MyUserControl` and `MyOtherControl` picks it up. But the `PropB` binding does not work. The property in `MyUserControl` is never updated. (I have a propertychanged callback set up with a breakpoint in it, but the breakpoint is never hit.) There is no errors or warnings logged to the output window like you would see in a binding failure.

What could be going on?

Comment: do you see any exceptions in the output window of your visual studio when you run in the debug mode?

Comment: Nope. No exceptions, no warnings or errors. Nothing. That's what puzzles me the most about this.

Comment: Just give it a try. Try removing the Mode=OneWayToSource

Comment: Still nothing. The propertychanged callback is not getting called, and no exceptions are logged.

Comment: Maybe there is a datatype mismatch. Check on that.

Comment: use Snoop to see what bindings are set at runtime

Comment: @DavidA. show us the code for your PropA and PropB in MyUserControl and MyOtherControl, i think that would help...